# Params from Twilio.device.connect() cannot be retrieved on server

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am developing a android application for VOIP using the Twilio Api. I am using node js for the server. What is the method by which I can retrieve the phone number passed in the connect() method,in the node js server?

//This is my connect() method

```
public void connect(String phoneNumber) {
        Map<String, String>param =new HashMap<String,String>();
        param.put("DialTo", phoneNumber);
        connection = device.connect(param,null);
        if (connection == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection does not exists");
    }
```

//node.js server

```
    var express=require('express');
    var app=express();
    var twilio=require('twilio');
    var acctId='';
    var authToken='';
    var applicationId='';

    app.get('/call',function(req,res){

        var caller_id="//SOME TWILIO NUMBER";
        var twiml=new twilio.TwimlResponse();
        var dialTo=req.query.param;
        console.log("Dialing to:"+dialTo);

        twiml.dial(dialTo,{callerId:caller_id});
        console.log("Calling...");
        console.log(twiml.toString());  
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    });


var port=process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server started on " + port);
});
```

It is giving me undefined for req.query.param

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio will take the array of values you pass into the connect method and turn each key/value pair into a querysting key/value pair.

I think in oyur case you need to change this line:

```
var dialTo=req.query.param;
```

to this:

```
var dialTo=req.query.DialTo;
```

Hope that helps.